# android fastboot lists nothing(Debian)

Tags: debian, android, bootloader

hi im new to rooting and am having problems unlocking bootloader i have 2 sdks installed on system one for root which im using to root my device and on for my user for ADT bundle. 
when i type adb devices it sees the device but fastboot cant see the device terminal output is below if anyone can help me that would be great thanks

```
@debian:~$ adb devices
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached 
0f3e0a22    device

@debian:~$ adb reboot bootloader (this does send device into fastboot)
@debian:~$ fastboot devices (nothing gets printed)
@debian:~$ sudo fastboot devices (nothing gets printed)
@debian:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

More information please.

Does dmesg say anything?

Can you increase the verbosity of fastboot by including 1 or more "-v" flags?

Are you using a newer version of fastboot?

Comment: i presume its the newist version of fastboot just installed it. dmesg outpu shows                                                                                                       `[ 2943.416801] usb 2-1.1: Product: MSM8960
[ 2943.416804] usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: Sasmsung
[ 2943.417325] cdc_acm 2-1.1:1.0: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.`

Comment: sorry i found this in dmesg output too `[ 2891.989713] usb 2-1.1: Product: SAMSUNG_Android
[ 2891.989716] usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
[ 2891.989719] usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: 0f3e0a22
[ 2891.990993] cdc_acm 2-1.1:1.1: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
`

Comment: sudo fastboot reboot gives me`<waiting for device>`

Comment: this is my 51.android.rules below

Comment: `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0502", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1004", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="22b8", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0fce", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0489", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1", SYMLINK+="android_adb", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"`